# Can I create a form to fill out a custom HTML email signature with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, email, html-email

I'm kind of familiar with coding, and I have heard that running script in an email signature is absolutely bad form; however, a client has asked me to create a way to allow their employees to input their own information into the signature so that they are all uniform. None have a coding background and I don't want to create 100 custom HTML signatures/create new ones for future hires. Only three "fields" would need to be customized.

So, I thought of sharing a simple web app like this (in its simplest form):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    function showEmail(){
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        display_email.innerHTML= email;
    };
</script>

<body>
    <!--INPUT TO CUSTOMIZE SIGNATURE--!>
    Email: <input type="text" id="email" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="showEmail()" value="Add" />

    <!--EMAIL SIGNATURE BEGINS--!>

    <p><span id="display_email"></span></p>
</body>
```

Would this be bad? It wouldn't really be "running script" in the email since they'd copy and paste the signature only (or am I just completely wrong). P.S. I will not be offended if this strategy makes no sense - any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this **PROBABLY** belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), another site in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @AndrewL64 The existence of Code Review doesn't change Stack Overflow's rules. Only close questions on Stack Overflow which are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrewL64 I wasn't asking for a code review. I just gave a loose example to supplement my train of thought - this specific code wasn't actually used.

Comment: @Peilonrayz OP gave the impression that their hypothetical code was working but they are trying to find out if given approach is a "good strategy" for avoiding repetitive code. That sounds like a code review regardless of whether it's off-topic or not to StackOverflow. Also, note the bolded and caps PROBABLY.

Comment: @mermi Regardless if your code is hypothetical or not, your question gave the impression that you have working "example" code and want to know if your "example" code was a good "strategy" for handling multiple users. That sounds like asking for a code review tbh. Also, as mentioned in the other comment, note the bolded and caps PROBABLY.

Comment: @AndrewL64 "OP gave the impression that their hypothetical code was working". Please familiarize yourself with Code Review's rules when recommending people to post on CR, "[Questions should not contain purely generic, hypothetical code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)". In your own words the question would be a bad fit for CR, which is why you shouldn't close ("I’m voting to close") because of mere assumption of other site's rules.

Comment: @AndrewL64 Actually, I was asking if the use of JavaScript as an in house tool on a web app would interfere with the generated HTML email signature's functionality across differing email platforms, because, as I said, I'm not familiar and was looking for expertise. I then proceeded to provide an example to show how I would hypothetically be using JavaScript. Thanks, probably.

Comment: @Peilonrayz The impression was from his comment "I just gave a loose example to...." posted after the close vote and not from the question good sir.

Comment: @mermi "....how I would hypothetically be using...." - Again, the question gave the impression that you have working code and wanted to know if the approach is a good/bad strategy. The hypothetical-ness was clarified afterwards in your comments. And you're welcome, probably.

Comment: Also, just wanted to stress yet again on the bolded and caps "PROBABLY" in the close-vote and also on the fact that the original question didn't mention anything about the code being a hypothetical example. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, in house tools are fine to make.

This is a rather good idea, because people have the opportunity to make sure they use their preferred name, (Jim instead of Jimmy). And its on them to complete the task, which is hopeful a part of onboarding. Below is a really low effort example of what it might look like. Feel free to use it as a starting point.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  const name = document.querySelector('[name="name"]').value;
  const phone = document.querySelector('[name="phone"]').value;
  const email = document.querySelector('[name="email"]').value;

  const template = document.querySelector('#template');


  template.textContent = `${name} - Example Corp (${phone}) | ${email}`;
})
```

```html
<h2>
  Email Signature Generator
</h2>
<div>
  Name: <input name="name">
</div>
<div>
  Phone: <input name="phone">
</div>
<div>
  Email: <input name="email">
</div>
<button>
 Generate
 </button>

<div id="template">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Glad I'm on the right track. My template is much more complex though. Would you say, like in my example, adding the variable span to exactly where I want it in my HTML table would be my best bet?

Comment: Oops - just played around with your code snippet and answered my own question! Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is highly not recommended in emails as all email clients (with a few exceptions) will not run your script. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients.

Creating a web app for your client is probably your best bet so they copy and paste the signature. Keep in mind though that you will have to use inline CSS as emails behave differently than web.